# Use regex to find a nest HTML element with a given attribute

Tags: regex

I want to be able to strip out certain HTML elements from a file using regex.
The elements have nested elements within them and I want to remove those as well.

Simplified examples:

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
<div style="display:none">
  <span>Some text</span>
</div>
```

I have a pattern like so `<([a-z]*)\s[^>]*display:none[^\/]*<\/\1>` which matches successfully on non-nested items.

How can I update the regex to include the nested elements as well?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it:

```
<([a-z]*)\s[^>]*display:none.*?(<\/\1>)
```

Explanation:

- `<([a-z]*)\s` Matches the starting element tag and a space
- `[^>]*` Matches to the end of the element tag
- `display:none` Ensures "display:none" is inside the element tag
- `.*?` Matching everything up until..
- `(<\/\1>)` The closing tag of the same type of element

Notes for anyone who stumbles across this answer:

- This does not work for self closing tags. (e.g. `<div />`)
- This does not work for void elements. (e.g. `<input>`)
- This does not work if the element contains a nest of the same type. (e.g. `<div style="display:none"><div></div></div>`)
- This **does** work over line breaks with the correct options (global, extended, single line)

Comment: For me it only works with `[\s\S]` instead of the `.` (dot), otherwise the line breaks prevent from matching the `<div>` with the nested element from the example.

Comment: @evilmandarine Nice catch! I'm using an option flag to allow `.` to match new lines. Like yours better